# Bash, ... check if a program is installed or not, using bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a little script that check if a program is installed or not. I am trying with tmux, ...

```
`tmux --help` | grep "tmux: command not found" &> /dev/null
if [ $? == 1 ]; then
    echo "tmux is not installed"
    exit
fi
```

After installation of tmux, I get:

```
usage: tmux [-2lquvV] [-c shell-command] [-f file] [-L socket-name]
            [-S socket-path] [command [flags]]
tmux is not installed
```

If a program is not installed, appair the string "tmux: command not found". This could explain why I grep output of `tmux --help` command. Is a correct way to check if tmux is installed or not?

The script alwais echoes "tmux is not installed". Even if I install tmux. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You don't want the backticks around `tmux --help` that will execute `tmux --help` and then try to execute the returned help string as a command.

Comment: Lol. You are perfectly right

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `command`, `type` and `hash` built-in functions to test whether a given command is usable in the current shell session.

This will not tell you if it is available in some location not in the current `PATH` however.

You should avoid using `which` for this purpose (even though that is the default suggestion you will get from many people) because it isn't a standardized tool (not completely) and it is an *external* tool as compared to the above which are all built-in to the shell (and is thus more expensive of a check).